# Prolog showing false on a rule

Tags: prolog

```
student(ram, cse).   /* ram is student of CSE branch */
student(kirat, com).
student(ajay, cse).
student(amit, cmt).
studies (cmt, uc).      /* CMT branch studies the module UC */
studies(cmt, pm).
studies(com, pm).
studies(com, aplc).
studies(com, ads).
studies(cse, aplc).
studies(cse, pm).
studies(cse, algorithms).
studies(cmt, pm).
classmate(X,Y):-student(X,Y).
```

These are the rules and facts I have been given. I am completely new to Prolog.
When I write `classmate(X,com)` it always shows false and on putting  `classmate(X,cse)` or `classmate(X,cmt)` it's giving the solution.

Comment: There is a syntax error in your program `studies (` one space too much. And `//` is not a valid comment in Prolog.

Comment: @false still not working.

Comment: Again: the `//` comments are **invalid**.

Comment: try writing them as `/* comment  */ `

Comment: Yeah its woking but now after giving the output it gives false at the end I've done wat you said. Also I want to create a rule such as "Find out the classmates in any branch (i.e cse, com or cmt)."

Comment: The posted problem isn't making sense. After you remove the syntax errors (bad comment delimiter, and the space after the `student` fact name) then the `classmate(X, com).` does indeed work as expected, and `classmate(X, cse or cmt).` fails as a syntax error, again as expected. In prolog, you can't just say, `cse or cmt`. I would recommend a prolog tutorial or the prolog manual for information about proper prolog syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me

```
1 ?- classmate(X,com).
X = kirat
2 ?-  classmate(X,cse).
X = ram ;
X = ajay.
```

Did you remember to put `.` at the end of the query you executed?

Try writing the comments as `/* comment*/`.

Apart from that,it works fine.

Comment: where? When I execute it,it doesn't. It just shows the name and stops

Comment: @user2334012 It shows `false` after showing all the available solutions because it ran out of solutions. The `false` in that context means, "no more solutions".

Comment: @mbratch can you give me the solution for this one "To count number of modules in all i.e. cse, cmt and com." when I just give cse , cmt or com then it will show how many number of modules are there. These modules are stored in the given facts of studies how would i make a rule for that.